# how to configure Ubuntu to connect to a TACACS server

Tags: login

I have two Ubuntu workstations which I want to configure to use our TACACS+ server for logon rather than their local accounts. How do I configure the workstation to use the tacacs servers?

Comment: Guide: http://www.networking-forum.com/blog/?p=200 man page for daemon configuration file: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/tac_plus.conf.5.html Another guide: http://dalikin.wordpress.com/2009/08/31/simple-install-tacacs-server-on-ubuntu-jaunty/ Have at least a look at the 1st 2 links and when you face a problem that has no clear solution ask away :)

Comment: @Rinzwind Why don't you put all that information into an answer?

Comment: @lucio cuz I never have had a tacacs+ server so I do not know for sure if those links work on Ubuntu. You can have the rep if you c/p it though ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind What do you mean with `c/p`? *I don't understand the popular English's abbreviations, for the time being.*  :-)

Comment: @lucio copy/paste ;)

Comment: Oh, right. Well, I meant that you could create an answer, to leave this question  *solved*, with a better format, benefiting future users. Also, taking into account, that the user has not logged in again since 15 Nov.

Answer (score 1):

There,
I found interesting project - **[tacacsGUI.com](http://www.tacacsgui.com)**. It is self-hosted front-end UI for tac_plus configuration. My installation was easy, try it. Plus it has some advantages like **Backup Maker** for auto backup, **Subnet searcher** for subnets collection etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mind but I'd just like to add this info for others...

I was able to get xtacacs Version 4.0 working for authentication on a Ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS 64 bit system, with a Cisco AS2511 only after I compiled it in 32bit mode (gcc -m32 ...).
If I compiled it to the default 64bit target, it got all sorts of weird errors, like syslog showing that username 'chris' was transposed to 'hcris'.

Of course I had to load the 32bit system libraries (sudo apt-get install ia32-libs) and the 32bit header files (sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib) first.

Answer (score 0):

**See ServerFault Post** [Authenticate Linux sshd with TACACS+ (Cisco ACS)](https://serverfault.com/questions/425020/authenticate-linux-sshd-with-tacacs-cisco-acs)

### Install the server

1. Add the linux server's hostname / ip address into Cisco ACS and restart the Cisco ACS service
2. Download the [tacacs+ PAM module](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tacplus/) from SourceForge.
3. Install `pam` development package for your linux distro.  RHEL / CentOS call it `pam-devel`; Debian / Ubuntu call it `libpam-dev` (a virtual package name for `libpam0g-dev`).
4. Untar the tacacs+ `pam` module into a temporary working directory
5. `cd` into the new folder created by `tar`.
6. As root: `./configure; make; make install`
7. As root, edit `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, and add this line as the first entry in the file:

   `auth       include      tacacs`
8. As root, create a new file called `/etc/pam.d/tacacs`:

```
    #%PAM-1.0
    auth       sufficient   /usr/local/lib/security/pam_tacplus.so debug server=192.0.2.27 secret=d0nttr3@d0nm3
    account    sufficient   /usr/local/lib/security/pam_tacplus.so debug server=192.0.2.27 secret=d0nttr3@d0nm3 service=shell protocol=ssh
    session    sufficient   /usr/local/lib/security/pam_tacplus.so debug server=192.0.2.27 secret=d0nttr3@d0nm3 service=shell protocol=ssh
```

### Per-Server / Per-user Instructions

As root on each server, create a local linux user account that matches the tacacs+ username for all required users.  The users can optionally use `passwd` to set their local password to whatever they like as a last resort; however, if they set a local password, they will be able to login locally at any time without `tacacs+` even if the service is available.

### pam_tacplus Service information

The details of how the `pam_tacplus.so` module works are in this [`pam-list` archived email](http://www.redhat.com/archives/pam-list/1998-October/msg00039.html)

Answer (score 0):

Below config is usefull to user authenticate without having users in linux machine.

```
auth      sufficient   pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok
auth      required     pam_krb5.so use_first_pass no_user_check

account   sufficient   pam_unix.so
account   required     pam_krb5.so no_user_check
account   optional     pam_permit.so
account   required     pam_time.so

password  sufficient   pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok sha512 shadow
password  required     pam_krb5.so use_authtok no_user_check

session   required     pam_limits.so
session   optional     pam_permit.so
```